# UI5: Calling a function in view from custom control

Tags: controller, sapui5, sap-fiori

Here is my actual situation:

I'm currently working on an application using UI5 and the MVC-principle. For functional reasons I have created a custom control. In this custom control there are a view functions (beside that I'm using a controller and a view).

Now, this is the actual question: How do I call a function from the custom control?

I have no problem with calling functions from my controller, but I am not able to call a function from my custom control.

Details:
In my "App.view.xml" I have linked my controller and my custom control:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="..." xmlns:core="..." xmlns:l="..." xmlns:f="..." xmlns="..." xmlns:customControl="..." controllerName="..." displayBlock="true">
```

I tried to call a function from custom control as follows:

```
<Button xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:customControl="..." text="Description" press="functionfromcustomcontrol"/>
```

Can anyone tell what's wrong with this code or what should I do to solve this problem?.

I've research alot but didn't found what I'm looking for.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML

```
<Button xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:customControl="..." text="Description" press="functionfromcustomcontrol"/>
```

looks odd. 
I assume that you defined an own "Button" as CustomControl derived from the sap.m.Button. Then the XML should look like this:

```
<customControl:Button text="Description" press="functionfromcustomcontrol"/>
```

Just take a look at the openUI5 Walkthrough [Step 34: Custom Controls](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db) to get an example

Comment: Thanks for the answer! No i didn't defined a own Button in CustomControl (i just created a function there)... i don't know how to do that (i'm completely new in programming custom extensions...). I try to go through the Walkthrough

Comment: I've worked through the Walkthrough but i still don't know how to implement a button in my xml which executes a function from custom control. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: any ideas please?

Comment: here is my code from the custom control and i want to execute the function getSignatureAsPng in my View: `getSignatureAsPng: function () {
    return this._getCanvasAsPicture("image/png");
   },

   _getCanvasAsPicture: function (sMimetype) {
    var canvas = $("#" + this.getId())[0];
    var image = canvas.toDataURL(sMimetype);
    return image;
   }` here is my code from the xml-button: `<Button xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:customControl="barcodeScanner.custom.controls" text="Clear" press="getSignatureAsPng"/>`

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to achieve, but I don't think that this is the right way. In my opinion every event of a control should be handled in the corresponding controller and THEN from that controller you can call a custom library function in another library/object/etc. I dont think that what you are trying to achieve is even possible (propagating your event to another function that is not in the controller).

Comment: ok thank you for your answer. Is this what you recommend: Define a event in my custom control and write a function in the "normal" controller, which executes the event of the custom controller? What is the best way to call a function from the custom controller in a view (XML) ?

Comment: First of all, you have a Button. That is not a "custom control", it's a standard control. Yes, in the button you assign a press event handler function, such as press="onDoSomething". Then you have a function onDoSomething() in your view controller. Inside this function you can call an external controller or library or whatever you need. What you mean by "custom control" is you have a "custom controller" or "library" right?

Comment: correct. My "custom control" is a custom controller. But I do not know how to call a function from the custom controller in my view controller. Can you help me here?

Comment: via dependency injection, like how you inject other dependencies into your controller, like Button, Controller, Dialog, etc. check here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui/methods/sap.ui.define